# Is it possible to pass query parameters via Django's {% url %} template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to add request parameters to a `{% url %}` tag, like `?office=foobar`.

Is this possible? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377425/456550) for a simple custom template tag to render query strings.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

No, because the GET parameters are not part of the URL.

Simply add them to the end:

```
<a href="{% url myview %}?office=foobar">
```

For Django 1.5+

```
<a href="{% url 'myview' %}?office=foobar">
```

Comment: Well, technically they are. According to [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), an HTTP URL takes the form: http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>.

Comment: @naktinis An HTTP URL, yes.  A Django URL, [not so much](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request).  So for various definitions of "URL", you are both correct :P

Comment: Doesn't this result in the trailing slash interrupting the url, like `example.com/myview/?office=foobar` instead of `example.com/myview?office=foobar`?

Comment: Yes but so what?

Comment: Imagine I want to nest query parameters, elegantly, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 47):

A way to mix-up current parameters with new one:

```
{% url 'order_list' %}?office=foobar&{{ request.GET.urlencode }}
```

Modify your settings to have request variable:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with parameters that are lists

Comment: @Arthur Is it Djangos bug?

Comment: that would be elegant indeed, but does not work for paging as it also adds the "page=1" of the previous page again from the GET params.

Answer (score 38):

**Use `urlencode` if the argument is a variable**

```
<a href="{% url 'myview' %}?office={{ some_var | urlencode }}">
```

or else special characters like spaces might break your URL.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. the `some_var` variable returns empty in the href but is shown to be filled if used elsewhere in the template. v2.1

Comment: @geoidesic thanks for the report, let me know if you find further the breaking commit / version release notes, or manage to reproduce on 1.9.

Answer (score 9):

First, a silly answer:

```
{% url my-view-name %}?office=foobar
```

A serious anwser: No, you can't. Django's URL resolver matches only the **path** part of the URL, thus the `{% url %}` tag can only reverse that part of URL.

Comment: Indeed. That makes sense too ... I just wish it was a little more elegant than that.

Comment: You could always write a more elegant custom tag - {% qpurl myview office=foobar %} for example. This could also process the values and encode them appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If your url (and the view) contains variable `office` then you can pass it like this:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' foobar %}
```

or like this, if you have more than one parameter:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' office='foobar' %}
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the above, nothing worked.
**My system has:**

- Python 3.8.10
- python3 -m django --version 4.0.3

Here's what worked for me:
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('single/', views.single, name='single'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def single(request):
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

**Calling from .html file**

```
<a href={% url 'single' %}?url={{url}} target="_self">
```

**Broswer URL**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsblog/single/?url=https://www.cnn.com/2022/08/16/politics/liz-cheney-wyoming-alaska-primaries/index.html
```

**[image: Output]**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% url 'myview' office=foobar %}
```

It worked for me. It basically does a reverse on that link and applies the given arguments.