# How to configure where to redirect after a log out in Django?

Tags: django, authentication

Just wondering where I can set the url to redirect to after logout. I know you can set the login url. I want to redirect to my home page.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Modern Django (2017+?) has a setting called `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`.

### Older Djangos / Original Answer

You don't need to overwrite or wrap anything.

According to the docs, you can just supply the `next_page` argument to the logout view. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
                          {'next_page': '/successfully_logged_out/'})
```

Comment: This does not work if you have done a generic import of all auth urls. Easier to use @YeRuizhi's answer below

Comment: @RunLoop I approve of this other method. Only problem is you have to remember to use it every single time you build said link. So if this works in a standard build, it's more reliable. If not, then the next easiest solution makes sense.

Comment: i can't undersand how to reverse this url from view.

Comment: This is an awesome solution.  I am pushing it right back to login page.  Is there a way to add a system message through this line as well? so as to create a popup?  "You have successfully logged out"

Comment: The forward slash at the start of 'next page' URL : '/successfully_logged_out/'  is vital, without it, Django attempts to concatenate the "logout" URL with the "successfully_logged_out" URL, this creates a new 'illegal' URL. Makes life a tad difficult if you want to present Users with your Login Page after they logout.

Comment: @Rickka indeed, it's a standard HttpResponseRedirect(next_page), so if you supply a relative URL, it will do a relative redirect.

Comment: Since Django 1.10, there is a better way : a setting for that, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615214/1570104

Answer (score 71):

One easier way:

Add 'next' parameter to your log-out request url. For example:

```
<a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}?next=/path_to_the_page"> Logout</a>
```

Then the logout view will do the trick for you.

For after-login-redirect, you can just simply set it in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/path_to_the_page'
LOGIN_URL = '/path_to_the_page'
```

Comment: Weird that there isn't just a LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL property.

Comment: Coming soon... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL

Comment: We have 2017 now and LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL is actually working :)

Comment: Good answer. Sticking this in my `base.html` and forgetting about it. :D (I'm using vintage Django on Debian Jessie :S so the new settings aren't available.)

Answer (score 42):

Since Django 1.10, you can define a `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` ([see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url))

Answer (score 23):

You can redirect user anywhere by using LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL in your setting.py file

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'url name to redirect'
```

Answer (score 14):

**Redirect to current page**

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={{ request.path | urlencode }}">{% trans "Logout" %}</a>
```

Tested in Django 1.9.

See also: [Is it possible to pass query parameters via Django's {% url %} template tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591525/is-it-possible-to-pass-query-parameters-via-djangos-url-template-tag)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me in case, when LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL didn't (coz I have different paths in testing and production environment).

Comment: On the other hand can use {{ request.get_full_path }} to get the full url (including the trailing query string) as well.
Example: "/music/bands/the_beatles/?print=true"

Answer (score 7):

You can even use named urls for your next parameter:

```
<a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}?next={% url 'homepage' %}"> Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your logout view, after you logout the user for good, return HttpResponseRedirect(url). Please [see here for more details](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) you can write your own logout view (which can be just simple wrapper) overriding the 'next' page.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the redirection URL on client level, you can do it in the `urls.py`:

```
(r'^management/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
```

And then in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}?next=/">
    Log out
</a>
```

Where the `next`, you point to the right URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your own urls (and not imported generic auth urls) and are using the standard django auth views, them you can simply add (template_name='example.html') in the path.

`path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'),name="logout")`

Answer (score 0):

add this in you project setting.py file
`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`

you can write your URL between ''
I use my index page for logout default redirect

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your project setting.py file:

```
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```