# django logout redirects me to administration page

Tags: django, logout

I have provided a simple login functionality. For logout, I tried to use the built-in one. This is my urls.py:

```
(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

And this is my template file:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
logged in as {{ user }}
(<a href="{% url "logout" %}">logout</a>)
{% else %}
```

I have also enabled the default django admin site. When I click `logout`, it shows me the administration logout view. How can I pass the logout next page attribute to tell django which view to render?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django redirect after log out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315100/django-redirect-after-log-out)

Comment: See [`settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url).

Answer (score 74):

If you are seeing the log out page of the Django administration site instead of your own log out page (`your_application/templates/registration/logged_out.html`), check the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting of your project and make sure that `django.contrib.admin` comes after `your_application`. Both templates are located in the same relative path and the Django template loader will use the first one it finds.

Comment: How is this answer answering " How can I pass the logout **next page attribute** to tell django which view to render?"

Comment: I didn't know that the logout template had to be named `logged_out.html`. Thanks a ton, you've put an end to almost a day of head-scratching :)

Comment: Wow. I did not find this in the documentation while reading about auth. Neat

Answer (score 21):

**Tested on Django 1.6:**

What I do is adding this into my `urls.py`:

```
(r'^management/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
```

And then used it:

```
<a href="{% url "django.contrib.auth.views.logout" %}?next=/">Log out</a>
```

For the `next` argument, there you point to the right URL.

**Tested on Django 2.1**

Append to `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]
```

And then use it in the template:

```
<a href="{% url "logout" %}?next=/">logout</a>
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views).

Comment: im not sure why ppl didn't mark this as correct answer! this worked for me!

Comment: The simpliest, works like a charm. I recommend this if you want to logout without the need to create another template for logout view.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest solution is:

1. Make sure your app comes *before* `django.contrib.admin` under installed apps in `settings.py`.
2. Make sure your template is called `logged_out.html`.

Answer (score 12):

According to docs, you can supply the next_page parameter to the logout view.

See [`LogoutView` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView.next_page).

```
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
    {'next_page': '/logged_out/'})
```

Comment: The result is: `Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Comment: maybe this logout is under an app and you need to specify also app name in that url

Answer (score 7):

You can put `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` in your `settings.py` file with a url name to redirect to, e.g. `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'`

Answer (score 4):

This is all fairly well explained in the manual, is there anything specific you don't understand?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
```

Alternatively if you don't want to create your own view

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

```
{% url 'logout' next='/some/url/' %}
```

Comment: I thought I can use built-in django logout view and parametrize it somehow - this wouldn't force me to define my own custom view.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: that's also an option, it's explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout

Comment: Then I get `Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'next': u'/some/url/'}' not found.`. I don't know what's wrong... The same error I get with the `login` from contrib...

Comment: Can you check which Django version you are running exactly? Also, how/where did you include your login urls?

Answer (score 4):

i was experiencing the same isssue following Django by example... found this url worked for me

```
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', { 'template_name': 'account/logout.html',}, name='logout' ),
```

Comment: How is this answer answering " How can I pass the logout next page attribute to tell django which view to render?"

Comment: Thanks!  This is the answer that worked for me.  Specifying the template name fixed it so it no longer switched over to the admin logout.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings.py and add this code. "/" will redirect you to home

```
# Where to redirect during authentication
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/" #To go to home after login instead of getting redirected to accounts/profile on login which is default
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/" #To logout back to the home page instead of the default admin logout page
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, you can put this in your settings.py to redirect when logging in and logging out:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/go-here-after-login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/go-here-after-logout/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Summary of the most common solutions:

Make sure that your_app comes before django.contrib.admin in your INSTALLED_APPS list in your settings.py file.

Also make sure that your log out page is called 'logged_out.html' as pointed out in the answers above. Mine was called logout.html and didn't work.

Comment: correct, my issue is with order of the INSTALLED_APPS list at settings.py.

Comment: but this also raise another problem because the admin panel logged out also redirect to frontend logout page

Comment: Can confirm 'logged_out.html' was the issue for me as I had a slightly different format for the template name.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the template to be rendered also in the href tag

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

  logged in as {{ user }}
  (<a href="{% url "logout" %}?next=myapp/templates/logoutmessage.html">logout</a>)

{% else %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

if you use the default values in settings.py. Works for Django 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the following to your `settings.py` file:

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'`
`LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'`

It tells Django to redirect you to whatever page you want to go to after logging in or out.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace loaders here, and auth templates will be found in "your_progect_apps/templates/registration":

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Django v2.1