# why does it renders django administration site instead of custom log out page

Tags: python, django, logout

I create my own template for logout page, but it loads default django logout page instead of it. according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34214067/8782552) I need to put *django.contrib.admin* after my app name in setting.py. I've already tried this but doesn't work for me.

setting.py:

```
.....
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'league',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, logout_then_login

 urlpatterns = [

url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/', logout, name='logout'),
url(r'^logout-then-login/$', logout_then_login, name='logout_then_login'),
```

logout.html

```
{% extends "league/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Logged Out{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Logged Out</h1>
{% if form.errors %}
<p>
You have been successfully logged out. You can <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a> again.
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please, add some code to your question

Comment: where is your logout url? update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use a custom logout page you have to tell django where is that page.

you do this with the `template_name`
your logout url:

```
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, { 'template_name': 'path_to/logout.html',}, name='logout')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using django v1.10 or newer, you can use the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL  setting property to redirect the logout page.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url