# django built-in authentication views not rendering templates

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uM0C.png)I made **registration** folder under my **templates** folder and add these thwo files(login.html & logout.html) in this folder.when i runserver i got no error but my **login** template in not rendering.only **base** template is render.please guide me?
here is all my code.

**Login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Please, use the following form to log-in. If you don't have an account <a href="{% url "register" %}">register here</a></p>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="login-form">
        <form action="{% url "login" %}" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
            <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
        </form>
        <p><a href="#">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView, LoginView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),

    #login and logout
    path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

**setting.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('logout')
```

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block  title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <span class="logo">Bookmarks</span>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul class="menu">
            <li {% if section == "dashboard" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="{% url "dashboard" %}">My dashboard</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "images" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li {% if section == "people" %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="#">People</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="user">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            Hello {{ request.user.first_name }}, <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post base.html

Comment: @aman i add base.html

Comment: You need to add `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in your base.html like you did for the title block.

Comment: @aman thanks now login template is rendering but after login when click logout i got this page.i add image above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467831/django-logout-redirects-me-to-administration-page   check this post.