# How do I manage to make a log out option in a webpage that will redirect me to the main home page?

Tags: python, html, django, api

I am trying to make a web application and I want a log out option in one of my template which will redirect to my home page. How should I do it?

I have a home page name 'home.html' which have a google sign in option by social o-authentication process and once signed in it will redirect it to another template named 'jumbotron.html'. But if I refresh and try logging it again it directly takes me to that template.

So I basically want a log out option on a template 'jumbotron.html' which will redirect me to the home page and have to log in again. How should I do it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315100/how-to-configure-where-to-redirect-after-a-log-out-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure where to redirect after a log out in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315100/how-to-configure-where-to-redirect-after-a-log-out-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `index` is name of your homepage url

You can specify your logout redirect url in passing *next_page* in `urls.py`
like this

```
(r'^logout/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': 'index'}
),
```

you can also set `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py

like

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL= 'index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume `home` as your homepage url.

In your urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

url(r"^logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
```

In your settings:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL= 'home'
```

In your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
```

If the logout url is inside any django app then:

```
<a href="{% url 'appname:logout' %}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
```

Comment: I tried doing what you have advised me to but while doing it the button appears but it does not redirect me to anywhere, I mean it does not show any effect.  @NiladryKar

Comment: Have you placed the logout url inside any django app?

Comment: Well no logout url is not inside any django app

Comment: Please check that you have `django.contrib.auth` in your installed app in settings.py file

Comment: I have edited my logout url...I have not placed the Caret `^` before in the regular expression..Please check

Comment: Apparently Its working when i use '<p class="text-center"><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Sign out</a></p>' in my template. But when i try to log in again it wont show me the google log in option rather it takes me directly to that template again. What should i do to log in again with a different user then?

Comment: Do you have set your login url?and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in your settings?

Comment: Did you have placed the logout link in your `home` template?

Comment: yeah i have set login url and login_redirect_url in settings. i do not know how to fix this. i am not been able to sign in with different google user.