# Django: Refer to an url name in a template and passing parameter

Tags: django

I know you can refer to a urlname in a template so that you don't need to hardcode your url links in your templates whenever you want to change them.

For example in a template, I use:

```
<a href="{% url 'urlname' parameter %}">The link</a>
```

My problem is, if I want to pass a more complex parameter to be used in the url regex. In my case, I want to pass a concatenation of two strings separated by an "_". Those strings come from Python objects and I don't get how to do that. Let's say for example, those strings are the firstname and lastname of a user.

I tried:

```
<a href="{% url 'urlname' "user.firstname_user.lastname" %}">The link</a>
```

And others tricks but none worked.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, you don't.

You either adjust your url to have two capture groups (which would also require a slight change to the view)

```
url(r'(?P<first_name>\w+)_(?P<last_name>\w+)/$', view_name, name='url_name')
{% url 'urlname' user.firstname user.lastname %}
```

Or you just find a different url that suffices.

Comment: ^^ Actually when you say it, it is just so logic! I nevertheless found a trick with the "with keyword" and the "add function" but it was quite dirty...

Comment: @MarAja - It sounds like you'd be better off creating a custom template tag, although Its still cleaner to just make a url to do it

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag). The good answer for you, assuming you're using posititionnal arguments :

```
<a href="{% url 'urlname' parameter=user.firstname_user.lastname %}">The link</a>
```

Assuming your url conf is like so :

```
url(r'^urlname/(?P<parameter>(catching regexp))$',...)
```

Comment: If you believe a question is a duplicate, then you should leave a link to it as a comment (and then later voting to close when you have 3k+ rep)

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but maybe his case isn't covered.