# django template url does not call django rest api

Tags: python, django, rest, api

I have following django rest api end point

```
url(r'^api/email-verification/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', EmailVerificationApiView.as_view(), name="email-verified")
```

and following is the html template where i am applying this api to verify a user, i.e after clicking the following `Activate` link, the above mentioned api endpoint will be called  and in back end the user will be flaged verified, but with the click of the html button it doesn't call the api.

```
<body>
          <tr>
            <td class="button">
              <div><!--[if mso]>
                <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:45px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:155px;" arcsize="15%" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ff6f6f">
                  <w:anchorlock/>
                  <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:regular;">My Account</center>
                </v:roundrect>
                  <a href="{% url 'email-verified' user_id %}">
                    Activate
                  </a>
              </div>
            </td>
           </tr>
<body>
```

after clicking the `Actvate` button, its redirecting me another page which give following statement

```
    Redirect Notice
       The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http:///api/email-verification/103/).

    If you do not want to visit that page, you can return to the previous page.
```

.I am relatively new in django and django rest api.Is there any other special way to call a django rest api in django template url tag?

**In mention**, the api is a **POST** api and the above given html template is a email template.

Comment: I think this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: whats the purpose of  href="http://" in  `<v:roundrect>` tag

Answer (score -2):

In your template you have

```
{% url 'email-verified' user_id %}
```

It should be:

```
{% url 'email-verified' pk=user_id %}
```

Comment: I doesn't work, i have updated my question also. after clicking the `Activate` button, its actully redirecting me a page which suggesting that i am trying to redirecting in invalid url like `http:///api/email-verification/103/`. Its actually happening from the begining, sorry that i didn't give it initially.

Comment: You got an extra `/` in your url, after the `http://` part: `http:///api/email-verification/103/`

Comment: Also, after reading the last part of your edit containing the fact that your api expect a `post`: How do you expect a post with a `<a>` link ? To submit a post, you need a form. And you cannot submit a post from a mail body.

Comment: Yeah you got right, i have change the method to GET, and its working now, but still there is another problem that i have to hardcoded the url like `<a href="http://localhost:8000/api/email-verification/{id}/">`, otherwise it doesn't apply the api.