# Django: download redirect error: local variable 'no_of_download' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I am creating a webpage for users to upload images and share images

Here is the screenshot of the detail page of an image (without error, before I added line`no_of_download += 1` in models.py) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFtoH.png)
What I wanted here is: 
**when a I clicked `download`button on ImageDetail.html, the Image will be stored to my computer and the `No. of downloads: 0` will change to `No. of downloads: 1`

here is my code:

views.py:

```
class ImageDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Image
    template_name='ImageApp/ImageDetail.html'
```

ImageDetail.html:

```
<a href="{{ image.get_img_url }}">Download</a>   //this is for someone to click 'download'
<p>The no. of Downloads of this image: {{ image.no_of_download }}</p>   // to show the total no. of downloads of this specific image
```

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,  blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.FileField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    no_of_download = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '-' + self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('imagebank:image-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_img_url(self):
        no_of_download += 1
        return self.photo.url
```

**ERROR:**
When I redirect to ImageDetail.html, there is this error message: `local variable 'no_of_download' referenced before assignment`

note that I DON'T want to use JavaScript here for some reason

Comment: Please put up more of your existing code in views.py, models.py (esp. UserProfile). This is too little to be of help.

Comment: ok .... i have updated it

Comment: Here you are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag

Comment: sorry, I dont understand how is it related to download....

Answer (score 0):

not sure I follow everything you're doing, but here's the first fix:

in get_img_url, change `no_of_download += 1` to `self.no_of_download += 1`

that will at least fix your exception.

Then your next step will be to call `save()` on the Image instance so that the change to no_of_download get's persisted...but that's a different question