# Invalid block tag: 'edit_url', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

I'm getting this error message from django, and don't understand why. Here I use extra code i know this error comes from that. But i don't know how to solve this. Here i'm assigning id to edit button. Please help me in that.

```
<tbody>
    {% for business_obj in business_objs %}
      {% edit_url="127.0.0.1:8000/addedit/"+ business_obj.id %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ business_obj.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ business_obj.business_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ business_obj.business_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ business_obj.business_phone_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ business_obj.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ business_obj.business_type }}</td>
          <td>{{ business_obj.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ business_obj.images }}</td>
          <td><a href="{% edit_url %}"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:blue"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'native:home_addbusiness_delete' %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:red"></i></a></td>

      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not define a template tag named `edit_url`, but want to use a [**`{% with ... %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) here:

```
{% for business_obj in business_objs %}
    {% with edit_url="127.0.0.1:8000/addedit/"|add:business_obj.id %}
        ...
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, you here should really use the [**`{% url ... %}` template tag [Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to do proper URL formatting. Something that might look like:

```
<a href="{% url 'native:addedit_business' pk=business_obj.id %}"><i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:blue"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Define NameSpace in Django URLs routing file. After that, you don't need to define the domain.  After that, you can refer to [How to add url parameters to Django template url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

This will solve your problem

Comment: What i'm trying is in my database i have 4 rows when i click edit button i want to edit that particular row only. How to do that using business_obj.id

Comment: Here are some solution                                                                                      1. You can use HTML modal                                                                                          2. if you need to update in the table or you can make every row with form and submit the form.                                                                                                      
3. Use Ajax