# Django url dispatcher using repath arguments

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my django app . I have endpoints for a package with the months like :

```
www.example.com/cart/packagename/months 

www.example.com/cart/stater/3
```

which i dont think will good as an url pattern I want something like :

```
www.example.com/cart/?package=stater&months=3
```

And also want to encode the parameters 'package=stater&months=3'

If anyone has any suggestions how to achieve that with django let me know. because before i worked with laravel and its pretty simple to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add url parameters to Django template url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Its also very simple to do in Django. The part after question mark here is called [**`URL Query String`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). You can get its value by:

```
def cart_view(request):
    packages = request.GET.get('package')
    months = request.GET.get('months')
```

As URL query string has nothing to do with actual URL, so you need to change your `url.py` to:

```
path('cart/', cart_view,name='cart_view'),
```

Comment: How i will add this to the radio button of months like when 3 months will select it will auto refresh and load the prices of 3 months package .

Comment: You need to write some JS for that and unfortunately that is not in the scope of this question. Better to ask a new one :)