# Including an Item Context to a Post Model to activate if statement in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an Item to a list view, the UserPost list view has already a Post context.

In my project, a user can add a post and add an item each is a different app with different models.

So In my UserPost list view, I have my Posts looped related to a specific user related to it.

What I am trying to do is check if this post.user has an item filtered by the same user and if it does exist a button show appears in the page linking to another page with this list of items related to this user.
To be more descriptive I want to check for `Item` for the `designer__post` and link to this page which is `{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}`

I hope this clears my question if there are any more clarifications required or code please let me know to add it.

I tried to use make use of an Exists subquery [Django-doc] but I didn't succeed it perfecting it

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user, admin_approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Here is the template user_posts.html

```
{% if item %}
 <a class="primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}" role="button">Go to items</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Go to items</button>
  </a>   
{% endif %}
```

here is the item models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

here is the designerlist views.py that I am trying to link to from the user post view if it is available

```
class DesignerPostListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "designer_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Item.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Here are the views related to the post model

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
]
```

Here are the views related to the item model

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', DesignerPostListView.as_view(),
         name='designer-posts'),
]
```

Projects URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
    path('score/', include('score.urls', namespace='score')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),

]
```

[image]

Comment: "if this post.user has an item filtered by the same user and if it does exist a button show appears in the page linking to another page with this list of items related to this user." All I get is that you want to add a button, but can you please explain the precondition more clearly?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I have added a more descriptive image I hope it helps

Comment: How is a Post related to an Item? Can you share a mockup with hypothetical data in the database?

Comment: @aaron The item and post are 2 different models in 2 separate apps. For example, a user can upload a post (consider it as an article) only, or he might have an item (consider it as a product) only, or he could have both and item and a post under his name. For each user, I have created 2 list views one for items and one for posts and I want to link each together by a button for easier navigation between these 2 pages. Does it make sense?

Comment: so basically the item is not bound by any post it is bound by perticular user so that means you need to show all the item for a perticular user in a post right

Comment: @KishanParmar correct, because when I am in `UserPostListView` I am seeing posts of User X who might have items under his name to be viewed in `DesignerPostListView` for the same User X, I want to link these 2 views together

Comment: @A_K from you problem you have to make a item related to post so if you put relation in item to the post as foreignkey it will already as related to user and a post

Comment: user_posts.html shows a (differently built) button regardless of `item`? I suppose the `item` in `{% if item %}` is a placeholder?

Comment: does the *"specific user"* is identified by the ***authentication***? I mean, are you trying to filter the `UserPostListView` and `DesignerPostListView` with ***logged-in user***?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu no it is not the currently logged in user it is a user requested from the home page

Comment: Can you add the URLs of the views?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added the URLs

Comment: Can you also add the ***root URL config***? because it seems your both "relevant views" are pointing towards the same URL

Comment: I added the URL of the project is this the root URL config you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to pass one context variable by overriding the **`get_context_data(...)`** method, that decides whether the ***user*** has **`Items`** or not

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    # rest of your code
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        has_items = Item.objects.filter(designer__username=self.kwargs['username']).exists()
        context['has_items'] = has_items
        return context
```

Then in your template, use this **`has_items`** variable by,

```
{% if has_items %}
    <a class="primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' username=view.kwargs.username %}" role="button">Go to items</a>
{% endif %}
```

Also, you were not passing the **`username`** to the **`url`** tag, it should be

```
{% url 'core:designer-posts' username=view.kwargs.username %}
```

here, I used `view.kwargs.username` to get the ***username*** from the URL

#### References

1. [`ListView.get_context_data(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data)
2. [`url` tag with kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

Answer (score 0):

in {% url %} item.designer  passes a user object you have to provide id for that like this

```
 <a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer.id %}">
```

Comment: I did as shown but it returned with `NoReverse Match` btw I dont want to loop the items I just want to link to it `<a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}">` if `{% if post.designer.item.exists %}`

Comment: @A_K hope this solves your problem new answer is added