# TypeError at /edit : edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry'

Tags: python, html, django

I am very new at Django and I am working on a web app project. this particular page is supposed to edit an entry and save the entry. but I keep getting the missing 1 required argument

*Views.py*

```
# editPage forms
class editform(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label='')


def edit(request, entry):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        page = util.get_entry(entry)
        return render(request,"encyclopedia/edit.html",{
            "form":SearchEntry(),
            "edit":editform(initial={'content': page}),
            "entry":entry
            })

    #If this is a POST request
    else:
        form = editform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(entry,content)
            page = util.get_entry(entry)
            page = mark.convert(page)
            return render(request,"encyclopedia/entry.html",{
                "form":SearchEntry(),
                "page":page,
                "entry": title
            })
```

*urls.py*

from django.urls import path

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("newEntry", views.newEntry, name="newEntry"),
    path("edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

*edit HTML*

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}


{% block title %}
    Edit {{name}}
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <form action= "{% url 'edit' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ edit }}
  <br>
  <input class="save btn btn-info" type="submit" value="save"/>
  </form>
  <p> Click the "save" button to save your entry to the encyclopedia.</p>
  <br>



<a href = "{% url 'index' %}"> Return Home</a>
{% endblock %}
```

*entry HTML*

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}




{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>{{title}}</h1>


    {{entry | safe}}

<a href = "{% url 'edit' %}"> Edit Content</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href = "{% url 'index' %}"> Return Home</a>
{% endblock %}
```

when I change this particular url:

```
path("edit/<str:entry>", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

I get a different issue:
**Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P[^/]+)$']**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add url parameters to Django template url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

Comment: Since your edit view requires a *mandatory* parameter named `entry`, you should update the `url` tag usage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `urls.py` file in this line:

```py
 path("edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

because `views.edit` is expecting that you must provide two-parameter `request` and `entry` in your `url`. And in your case **entry** is missing. Try to add entry in your urlspatterns path, in this case, I'm expecting your entry is `int`.

```py
path("edit/<int:entry>", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

and this entry can be your model pk or anything else you want. After modifying your `urlspatterns` whenever you call edit view in your **html** you need to do this:

```html
{% url 'edit' entry=your_entry_value %}
```

instead of:

```html
{% url 'edit' %}
```

Comment: For more clear answer share your `utils.get_entry()` function.

Comment: jade                                                                             the util.get_entry() takes in strings:                                                                  `def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
   ` try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None`

Comment: the util.get_entry() takes in strings:                                                                  ```def get_entry(title):
    """
    Retrieves an encyclopedia entry by its title. If no such
    entry exists, the function returns None.
    """
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the entry as the second variable:

```
def editWiki(request):
    wikiPageName = request.GET.get("wikiPageName")

edit(request):
    entry = request.GET.get("q")
```

On the html side when some one clicks the edit button pass that q parameter:

```
<form action="/edit" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value={{entry}} />
        <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

**Explanation :**
Once you hit the button the entry will be sent in the get request as q parameter value:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit?q=CSS