# No reverse match django with slug_pattern

Tags: python, django, url

So I want to insert a url from urls.py, but because we have a slug_pattern arg, i'm confuse how to do that.

Below are the traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/universitas-indonesia

Django Version: 1.11.20
Python Version: 2.7.15
Installed Applications:
('neliti',
 'publisher',
 'accounts',
 'hal',
 'mtam',
 'haystack',
 'django_countries',
 'storages',
 'select2',
 'modeltranslation',
 'tastypie',
 'mathfilters',
 'fastsitemaps',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions')
Installed Middleware:
('corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'publisher.middleware.CustomDomainMiddleware',
 'publisher.middleware.IndexingMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'publisher.middleware.RemoveSlashMiddleware',
 'publisher.middleware.ToLowercaseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'publisher.middleware.NonHtmlDebugToolbarMiddleware')


Template error:
In template E:\Project\neliti\backend\publisher\templates\publisher\headers\sub-menu\sub_menu_repository.html, error at line 51
   Could not parse the remainder: '-indonesia' from 'universitas-indonesia'   41 :       <li>
   42 :         <a href="#">Policies</a>
   43 :       </li>
   44 :       <li>
   45 :         <a href="#">For developers</a>
   46 :       </li>
   47 :     </ul>
   48 :   </div>
   49 : 
   50 :   <div class="section">
   51 :     <a id="contact" href=" {% url 'organisation_detail' slug=universitas-indonesia %} ">
   52 :       <div class="header">
   53 :         CONTACT
   54 :       </div>
   55 :     </a>
   56 :   </div>
   57 : </div>
```

**The urls.py look like this**

we use OrganisationDetailView and slug_pattern

```
slug_pattern = '(?P<slug>[a-z0-9_\\-]+)'

url(r'^%s$' % slug_pattern, cache_page(content_page_cache_time)(OrganisationDetailView.as_view()), name='organisation_detail'),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

**My Organisation view look like this**

```
class OrganisationDetailView(NelitiDetailView):
    model = Organisation
    filter_set = 'Publication'
    template_name = 'publisher/organisation_detail.html'
    display_filters = ['language', 'year', 'contribution', 'type', 'grade', 'country', 'province']

    def get_select_and_prefetch_objects(self):
        return self.model.objects.select_related(
            'primary_type', 'country', 'style_settings'
        ).prefetch_related(
            'parents', 'disciplines'
        )

    def get_search_box_placeholder(self):
        return _("Search %(name)s repository") % {'name': self.object.name_short}

    def get_narrow_query(self):
        # return 'author_org:"%(pk)s" OR funder:"%(pk)s" OR publisher:"%(pk)s"' % {'pk': self.object.pk}
        return 'repository:"%s"' % self.object.pk

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Add journal_lists and conference_lists to context

        # order_by('title') doesn't work, probably because half the titles are in title_en and half in title_ind
        journal_set = sorted(Journal.objects.indexed().filter(
            Q(primary_publisher__in=self.object.descendants) | Q(secondary_publishers__in=self.object.descendants)).distinct()
            , key=lambda x: x.title)
        # According to Anton, don't include proceedings published by descendent organisations
        conference_set = sorted(ConferenceNew.objects.indexed().filter(
            Q(primary_organiser=self.object) | Q(secondary_organisers=self.object)).distinct()
            , key=lambda x: x.name, reverse=True)

        for obj_set, key in [(journal_set, 'journal_lists'), (conference_set, 'conference_lists')]:
            n = len(obj_set)
            if n == 0:
                kwargs[key] = []
            elif n <= 6:
                kwargs[key] = [obj_set]
            else:
                split_point = int(math.ceil(n/2))
                kwargs[key] = [
                    obj_set[:split_point],
                    obj_set[split_point:],
                ]
        favicon = get_favicon_href(self.model, self.object)
        kwargs['favicon'] = favicon
        return kwargs
```

I've tried to do any related combination to insert the url, but found no solution, if you can give any insight it'll be helpful

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Update your html `<a>` tag. `universitas-indonesia` should also be in single quotes `slug='universitas-indonesia'`

```
<div class="section">
 <a id="contact" href=" {% url 'organisation_detail' slug='universitas-indonesia' %} ">
    <div class="header">
       CONTACT
     </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Get slug dynamically assuming  URL has ?var1='universitas-indonesia'

```
<div class="section">
 <a id="contact" href=" {% url 'organisation_detail' slug=request.GET.var1 %} ">
    <div class="header">
       CONTACT
     </div>
 </a>
```

Do update your var1 variable according to your URL.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks Akash

Comment: Related to that, can i dynamically change the slug into what the window.location value? Thanks

Comment: You can get the URL value in the views.py file by request.GET method and then pass it to HTML through context and in HTML you can use that variable. @Studentofcode

Comment: Oke can you give me one simple example of that ? Much appreciated

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag) you can follow this question hope so it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I've been looking up, but still have many confusion around it, do you have any alternative on it?

Comment: I have updated the answer try with that, hopefully, that will help. @Studentofcode