# How to pass a url parameter to the url tag in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.1

I have URLs configured so that I can corretly use the following in my template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'sitemember:profile' 'bobby' %}">{{ user.username }}&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
```

Where user.username resolves to 'bobby'

How do I pass the variable `user.username` to the `url()` tag, so that the URL resolves correctly as:

> https://localhost:/user/bobby (as an example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add url parameters to Django template url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify this in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'sitemember:profile' user.username %}">
```

Comment: I get: `Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user\\/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/$']
`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: that is because the `username` is empty, or `user` does not exists in the template. This is what the error is about it says *arguments `('',)`*, so it has one parameter, but that resolved to the empty string.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks very much. That makes sense. The error message was a bit cryptic, but yes, it makes sense now that you explained it.