# Django .Reverse for 'doctor' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern (s) tried: ['doctor / (? P <pk> [^ /] +) / $']

Tags: django

Framework Django.
I am trying to create a link to the profile of each user (doctor) by creating an automatic url by his id. an error appears: Reverse for 'doctor' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern (s) tried: ['doctor / (? P  [^ /] +) / $']

I suppose I need to add a second parameter to the template link, but I can't figure out that "{% url 'doctor' ??%}"

html

```
 ..."{% url 'doctor'  %}"...
```

view.py

```
def doctor(request, pk):
    doctors = Doctor.objects.get(pk)
    return render(request, 'main/doctor.html', {'doctors': doctors})
```

urls

```
path('doctor/<str:pk>/', views.doctor, name='doctor'),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add url parameters to Django template url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: Pass the parameter like this:

{% url 'doctor' pk=doctors.pk %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the pk parameter like this `{% url 'doctor' doctor.pk %}`

also primary keys are usually of the integer type so you could make this correction in your urls.py

```
path('doctor/<int:pk>/', views.doctor, name='doctor'),
```

Comment: doesnt work, error Reverse for 'doctor' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['doctor/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 1):

the primary key is a type of integer instant of a string so we need to pass the int in the `url.py`.

so the `url.py` should look like this,

```
path('doctor/<int:pk>/', views.doctor, name='doctor'),
```

and if you want a specific doctor with some primary key you can pass that in the template context in that case you don't need to query the database with the database manager. just simply pass the primary key to the template and django will handle the rest for you.

in `doctor.html`,

```
<a href="{% url 'doctor' pk %}">doctor with special pk </a>
```

for more information, you can refer to the official doc [reverse-resolution-of-urls.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)

Comment: doesnt work, error Reverse for 'doctor' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['doctor/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 1):

Probably a typo but it's worth the shot
In the `views.py` file you pass the variable `doctors`
so in your template edit

`{% url 'doctor' doctor.pk %}`

to

`{% url 'doctors' doctors.pk %}`