# Django Templates - How can I reference context inside HTML tags?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to create an email template. I've set up my context and everything is fine, however when it comes to passing a URL link through an `<a>` tag, I'm not sure where/how to place the context variable:

Here is how I do it:

```html
<td>
  <a href="{{url}}">Verify Email</a>
</td>
```

However, I don't seem to get the expected results, did I use the `url` variable wrong above?

```py
context = {
  'name': user.first_name,
  'url': absurl
}
html = render_to_string('email/email_confirm.html', context)
```

The `name` context is working just fine on my template.

Comment: is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57026556/4984493

Comment: Isn't that reference for paths inside `urls.py`? This specific URL is not in my paths.

Comment: Did you return an `HttpResponse` after rendering the template with your context?

Comment: then, what you did is just fine. Your URL still works too if just place it as it is without tags or anything, but since you need your text to be clickable anchor tag is the way here

Comment: Okay let me do some further testing, I am returning a regular 201 Response if the email is sent.

Comment: Are you sure that `absurl` is not empty?