# href not accepting loop Django

Tags: django

```
<table id="tabledata" class="tablecenter" style=" position: static; top:50%;">
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Remove User</th>
</tr>

{% for user in all %}
<tr>
    <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td> 
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{% if user.is_staff %} Admin {% else %} Practitioner {% endif %}</td>
    <td><a class="openButton" onclick="openForm()">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'delete_user' pk=user.id %}" class="openButton">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

After running the server on local, the page gives syntax error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fifk7.jpg)

Comment: Share the `urls.py`.

Comment: url(r'^delete_user/<int:pk>', views.delete_user, name='delete_user'),

Comment: I think no user exist with pk=1 can you check ?

Comment: even if I remove pk, its the same error

Comment: The solution given on the below link worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `url` and `path` syntax. You use of *path converters* with [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path), so:

```
# app_name/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('delete_user/<int:pk>/', views.delete_user, name='delete_user'),
    # …
]
```

Comment: no, need to delete a record from the loop. So I am passing user.id in:
<td><a href="{% url 'delete_user' user.id %}" class="openButton">Delete</a></td>
to delete it on the next confirmation page. But it shows syntax error

Comment: @MithunSawant: then likely in that view there is a syntax error...

Comment: But the same works on the below link:
https://arbcoms.com/19-how-to-delete-data-in-django-with-confirm-delete-prompt/

Just not working for me. I have attached a screenshot as well.

Comment: @MithunSawant: take a look at the traceback: this should indicate where the syntax error is located...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

According to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

```
<table id="tabledata" class="tablecenter" style=" position: static; top:50%;">
<tr>
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th>Remove User</th>
</tr>

{% for user in all %}
<tr>
    <td>{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</td> 
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{% if user.is_staff %} Admin {% else %} Practitioner {% endif %}</td>
    <td><a class="openButton" onclick="openForm()">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'delete_user' user.id %}" class="openButton">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT

In the tutorial guy is using this url

```
url(r'^delete_user/<str:pk>', views.delete_user, name='delete_user')
```

but you are using

```
url(r'^delete_user/<int:pk>', views.delete_user, name='delete_user')
```

Comment: @mithun sawant can you try with this template ?

Comment: even without pk, its the same error

Comment: does any user exist with the given id ? share urls.py

Comment: so I tried to use the delete method given on this link referring the video (https://arbcoms.com/19-how-to-delete-data-in-django-with-confirm-delete-prompt/)

but using href="{% url 'delete_user' user.id %}" this href it shows syntax error and after removing user.id, the page loads.

Comment: @MithunSawant Check my updated answer.

Comment: even if I change the url's, the html page shows syntax error only
<td><a href="{% url 'delete_user' user.id %}" class="openButton">Delete</a></td>

Same as the screenshot mentioned in my question