# How to fix multiple anchors leading to the same link error in Django?

Tags: html, href, anchor

Both of the anchors links to the  href that leads to the stack overflow page. For reference, (in case this is a confounding variable), I'm using the django environment if that means anything.

```html
<div>

  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/" style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; right: 80px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" id=1>
        Something1
    </a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag" style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; right: -80px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" id=2>
        Something2
    </a>

</div>
```

I initially tried using django variables but later swapped to these 2 links in order to debugg it. It still had the similar issue of both anchors leading to the latter href. I'm pretty new to this so I need a bit of help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are positioning them both at the bottom with width 100%. This means that they will be overlapping. And they are, and so only the top one will intercept the clicks for the overlapping section.

---

If you add a semi transparent background to the anchors you will see the overlap that is happening

```css
a{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

```html
<div>

  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/" style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; right: 80px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" id=1>
        Something1
    </a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag" style="position: absolute; bottom: 30px; right: -80px; width: 100%; text-align: center;" id=2>
        Something2
    </a>

</div>
```

The darker are is the overlap.

---

Perhaps a solution like the following, where i move the whole container to the bottom and style the elements to split the available space between them (using flex) is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.bottom-links {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
}

.bottom-links a{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-links">
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/" id="1">Something1</a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345392/how-to-add-url-parameters-to-django-template-url-tag" id="2">Something2</a>
</div>
```