# How to get rid of ampersand in url -- Django?

Tags: python, django, pagination, ampersand

I think I understand the use of django's template tools: `{% autoescape off %}` and `{{ somehting|safe }}`, but I'm not sure they apply to what I need.  And if they do, they aren't working...

So, I have a multiple forms with get and post methods on the same page.  Both methods (for searching and posting) retain the `&` symbol in the url. But when I use the get method(search) then use the post method after, I get `&amp` ; instead of `&`.

navigate to page:
`.../something/`
get method after returns:
`.../something/?search=somethingelse&search_location=anotherthing`

pagination works well still (so its not hrefs)
post method after all this returns:
`.../something/?search=somethingelse& amp;search_location=anotherthing& amp;page=5`

and if I keep posting I get a sequence of amp;:

```
.../something/?search=somethingelse&amp;amp;amp;amp;search_location=anotherthing&amp;amp;amp;amp;page=5
```

I think it might be the `{{crsf_token}}` require for post forms that encodes it.
I also tried `mark_safe()` in the `views.py`
I've been looking for some time now.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am not sure you question is well formed, since the actual code is missing. Have a look at [this SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591525/is-it-possible-to-pass-query-parameters-via-djangos-url-template-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The link you have points to a href problem.  It's a form with post method problem tho. I was really just looking to see if there were any ampersand decoding possibilities for csrf_token.