# How to stop Django from escaping the # symbol

Tags: python, django, svg, escaping

I am trying to use SVG sprites for the icons in a site, like this:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="{% static 'images/site-icons.svg#icon-twitter' %}"></use>
</svg>
```

However this doesn't work because the # gets escaped by Django and so I end up with:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="/static/images/site-icons.svg%23icon-twitter"></use>
</svg>
```

So no icons are rendered.
I have isolated that the problem is the escaping, since it works if I paste the contents of `site-icons.svg` in the template, and do

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use>
</svg>
```

so the problem is in the escaping.

Does anybody know how to avoid this escaping from happening?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to pass query parameters via Django's {% url %} template tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4591525/1324033)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to move the id after the static tag

```
{% static 'images/site-icons.svg#icon-twitter' %}
```

should be

```
{% static 'images/site-icons.svg' %}#icon-twitter
```

The reason behind this is that the static tag's job is to find the path to a static file, so all it needs is the file's location, anything extra needs to be added after so that when the template is rendered, it appears as a single (concatenated?) link