# Get onclick url with request in django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a template like below:

```
 <a href={{j}}>
  <img src="{{k}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#myModal" style="width:350px;height:200px;">
</a>
```

I have a function like below:

```
 def function_url(request):
   a = get_the_value_of_{{j}}  # how to get the value of {{j}}
```

How to send the `{{j}}` value to the function (function_url) when user clicks on the photo url  either with ajax or django?

Comment: you want to identify which link the user clicked is that it?

Comment: I tried this one but it did work for me. [This is how I soleved it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73389475/848677)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create new path in the `urls.py`. Assuming you use path from Django 2.0, if not use url.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('clicked-on-img/<str:value>/', views.function_url, name='url-name'),
    ...
]
```

**views.py**

```
def function_url(request, value):
    a = value # got it!
```

and in the template use it as

```
<a href="{% url 'url-name' value='img1' %}">
    ...
```

**EDIT**:
changed double quotes to single quotes in the `<a ... value='img1'>`

Comment: tnx, i will try and let u know