# How to link tags to search results in a Django Blog?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am building a blog in django and am using django-taggit. I'm trying to figure out how to tie the link of a tag to a search result page that shows all of the posts using that tag.

I already have the search page created, I know how to filter queries to the page to bring the correct results, and know how to link to the page itself `{% url 'search' %}`.  But how would I pass queries to the page from the template?

For instance, if I have a post tagged "dog" I want users to be able to click on the tag "dog" and be taken to the search page that only has results for posts also tagged "dog".

The [django documentation for class views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) does not have examples of this.  And every tutorial resource so far has been focused on the filtering and displaying of the search page itself rather than linking to it with desired queries in an `<a>` tag instead of a `<form>`.

In short, how do you make an `<a>` link pass a query into a url, like how an `<input>` would to a  `<form>` action in Django?

Comment: Please organize your question more? It's really hard to read and notify the problem.

Comment: I organized it more. I hope that makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for organizing it but it's hard to understand your problem. You want to use `<a>` tag instead of `<form>` tag? It's impossible because form send POST request and a tag is just redirecting (GET). You can make your own button to send ajax request to use one click button.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591525/is-it-possible-to-pass-query-parameters-via-djangos-url-template-tag) , it is

```
<a href="{% url 'myview' %}?q=foobar">
```